# GAE refuse to deal with http requests containing Host headers for security reasons

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, http-headers

I want to send a http request from my application on GAE to another application but the url of the other application is something like this " http://[host-number]/[payloads] "

the issue that GAE refuse to deal with this type of header, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests)
.
[image]

So, my question is how to solve this issue and use the same url and make GAE accept it.
By the way, I am using the standard example [urlfetch](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/urlfetch)

Comment: Why do you need to modify the `Host` HTTP header?

Comment: the google app engine refuses to deal with this type of url, so I didn't say I want to modify the header, unfortunately I can't modify it because I use it from another application that I have to connect with

Comment: what do you mean by "this type of url"? I don't understand what you're trying to do, are you trying to make outbound request or accept inbound request?